# Formatting maple for latex

Tags: formatting, export, maple2e

I am doing some linear programming in maple, and sometimes the matrices are quite large. I know that maple have a /latex(expression) function, but when I have a vector, that has fractions in it, it outputs:

```
\left[ \begin {array}{ccccccc} -23&0&0&-1&-8/3&0&-1/3
\\ \noalign{\medskip}9/2&1&0&1&2/3&0&-1/6\\ \noalign{\medskip}7/2&0&1&
1&1/3&0&1/6\\ \noalign{\medskip}3&0&0&3&-1/3&1&1/3\end {array}
 \right]
```

There are many things wrong with this, first of all when you copy+paste this into latex, it does not work since there is no space after the `&` also it displays fractions as `-1/6` instead of `-frac{1}{6}`. Is there other packages to export maple to latex, or a way to edit the format of the current one? Hope you guys have the answer :-)

Comment: Related: [MaplePrimes: Any alternatives to Maple's LaTeX?](http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/200725-Any-Alternatives-To-Maples-LaTeX) -- this has been a long-standing issue with them (since at least 2007). Going to fire up Maple 18 momentarily and see what third-party alternatives look workable.

Comment: Yeah, this is going to take a while. No idea if there's anything workable in that pile of posts above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking at it, if only maple would be strict about its formatting, sometimes it does use frac and sometime it doesn't..

Comment: I'm not enough of a Maple user to come up with a *good* answer, but here's what I got somewhat working: [this answer from Joe Riehl](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/43828-Better-LaTeX-Output-From-Maple#comment81960) applies regular expression substitutions to Maple's built-in LaTeX output. [John Fredsted's sample](http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/40243-Maple-Expressions-To-LaTeX-Converter) is a good stress test. The `_LatexSmallFractionConstant` variable controls when `\frac` is used. Set it to 0 to force it all the time, and 50 is the default.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you to solve the problem. You need to delete all strings   "**\noalign{\medskip}**" in your code

It works perfectly:

```
\left[ 
\begin {array}{ccccccc} 
-23  & 0 & 0 & -1 & -8/3 & 0 & -1/3\\ 
 9/2 & 1 & 0 &  1 &  2/3 & 0 & -1/6\\ 
 7/2 & 0 & 1 &  1 &  1/3 & 0 &  1/6\\ 
 3   & 0 & 0 &  3 & -1/3 & 1 &  1/3
 \end{array}\right]
```

You can test at here: http://www.wiris.com/editor/demo/en/mathml-latex